# Fixate Pulse's default Sound level

Tags: pulseaudio

[image: Input sound levels]

My Microphone input level constantly increases gradually with speaking. I normally set the level at, say 20% but it rapidly increases. I would like the sound levels not to be altered in anyway.

Can this be done in PulseAudio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that enabling the echo cancellation module in pulseaudio has caused this "alternating" behavior. Disabling the module from */etc/pulse/default.pa* resolves the issue.

Echo cancellation filter, loaded in pulseaudio by adding *load-module module-echo-cancel* at the module loading section, is a filter that provides more echo and noise cancellation for input devices. However, it is known to cause bugs.